# SVG pattern behaves different on different browsers

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg

I have been trying the SVG code below on Chrome 48 and IE 11 and it renders differently. In particular, IE does not recognize the "viewBox" tag in the pattern definition.

Is there a workaround to get this rendering identically on Chrome and IE ?

```
 <svg id="svg" width="1400" height="1100" >
 <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" viewBox="10 10 20 20" >
       <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff" />
    </pattern> 
 </defs>

 <g>
    <rect x="100" y="100" width="300" height="300" stroke="green" 
    stroke-width="3" fill="url(#pattern1)" />
 </g> 

 </svg>
```

[Chrome vs IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBiPu.png)

Comment: Don't use a viewbox to clip your shape - just draw a filled arc instead?